# Placement of Disconnect switch

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch

I am trying to finish a job an electrician abandoned.

A line was run from the house to a garage for power at the garage.  I was going to hook things up.  I understand that I need a disconnecting means.  This is a 30 Amp line run from the house breaker. So I was thinking about using a 30 am non-fused AC disconnect.

I have a question about placement of the disconnect.  The line comes into an outside porch of the garage, then conduit goes up the porch structure and then through the wall into the garage itself at about 8 feet from the floor.  My understanding is that you want to put the disconnect where it comes into the building.  So.... where would that be exactly?

I would *prefer* to run conduit from where the line comes into the garage itself down the wall to about 4 feet from the floor and put the switch there.   I think putting the disconnect in the porch of the garage is just.... well... dumb.  Does anyone have any advice on this?

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: This is USA, Ohio, Cuyahoga County.  Original building built circa 1920.  The porch on the garage is a 'screened in' porch.  but pretty much it is open

Comment: The maximum height of the disconnect is 6'7" but there is no minimum height. The "feeder" is protected by a breaker in your service panel so it can be at the most convenient location.

Comment: Thanks Ed, Thats kinda what I was thinking, and hoping.  I read the code, but I just was not sure on how exactly to apply it to my situation.

Comment: Is this an overhead or an underground feeder, and what is it servicing?

Comment: Im thinking a small sub-panel makes more sense than a disconnect.  Is there 4 #10's already run? Is that why you said 30 amp?